# dynamic menu and content from json

Tags: android, json, menu

i want to create menu and content from json, can you please give me a hint to parse this json string?

here is my json :

```
    {
  "menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "menuitem": {
      "gadget": [
        {
          "judul_video": "Godigi TV",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": "Kakashi Article"
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "TVRI Nasional",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "ANTV ",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        }
      ],
      "animasi": [
        {
          "judul_video": "Godigi TV",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": "Kakashi Article"
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "TVRI Nasional",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "ANTV ",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        }
      ],
      "techno": [
        {
          "judul_video": "Godigi TV",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": "Kakashi Article"
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "TVRI Nasional",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "ANTV ",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        }
      ],
      "cgt": [
        {
          "judul_video": "Godigi TV",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": "Kakashi Article"
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "TVRI Nasional",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "ANTV ",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        }
      ],
      "info": [
        {
          "judul_video": "Godigi TV",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": "Kakashi Article"
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "TVRI Nasional",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "ANTV ",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        }
      ],
      "news": [
        {
          "judul_video": "Godigi TV",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": "Kakashi Article"
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "TVRI Nasional",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        },
        {
          "judul_video": "ANTV ",
          "url_video": "url for video",
          "url_poster": "url for poster",
          "artikel_video": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

what i to output is : 
the animasi, gadget, techno, etc is for menu in list view and the array from them is content.

please help, i try to search but have no idea with this. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse try this

```
JSONOBject jb = new JSONObject("jsonstring");
JSONOBject jb1 = jb.getJSONObject("menu");
String id = jb1.getString("id");
String value = jb1.getString("value");
JSONObject jb2 = jb1.getJSOnObject("menuitem");
JSONArray jr = (JSONArray)kb2.getJSONArray("gadget");
for(int i=0 ;i<jr.length();i++)
{
     JSONOBject jb3 = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
     String judulvideo = jb3.getString("judul_video");
     String url_poster = jb3.getString("url_poster");
     String artikel_videor = jb3.getString("artikel_video");
}
```

Similarly parse the JSONArray  "techno": [ and others

`{` represents JSONObject node

`[`represents JSONArray node

You can also use Gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/